# Why do dropdown menus have a space between the highlighted item and the border of the menu?

Tags: dropdown, drop-down-list

Why do dropdown menus have a space between the highlighted item and the border of the menu?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Why do dropdown menus have a space between the highlighted item and the border of the menu?

Comment: This is more of visual style preference than standard.

Comment: I feel like this is a result of the way UI elements are implemented. But perhaps the answer to this question is more appropriate for a different StackExchange site.

Comment: The way it is in my environment (Qt), the dropdown itself is a list-widget, and the items are list-items. They can be styled separately, including the margins of the last item to give the above effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No reason at all. This is not even a standard pattern. There are examples without it that work well as well:

[image]

You could do both ways.

More relevant **question for a graphical designer** point of view rather than UX.